# How to add class when style is scoped?

Tags: templates, vue.js

This example should paint body in red color, but it doesn't because of `scoped` attribute.

```
<template>
   <div></div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
      name: 'test',
      props: {},
      mounted(){
         document.body.classList.add('highlight');
      }
   }
</script>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
   .highlight {
      background-color: red;
   }
</style>
```

Is there some workaround for this case?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need scoped styles because your styles are not scoped to your component.
If you need to have both scoped to component styles and global styles, you should declare two style tags. Example in [official docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#mixing-local-and-global-styles).
However, you should avoid global styles.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a scoped class to an element (`body`) outside the component!

All classes declared in scoped style of a component can be used only for elements inside that component because the class name is automatically changed to something like this: `.highlight[2d35fds3sd]`!

And all elements inside the component have that unique id :

```
<template>
  <div 2d35fds3sd>
     <span 2d35fds3sd>     </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

but body element does not have this unique id!

So if you want to apply a class to body, you have to put that class in a global css file.